# unity 2D look at upside down

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a patrolling 2D object that I want to look at the target it's moving towards. The problem is sometimes the object turns upside down, when the Z rotation has a high number.

```
Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
  float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y,dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

  transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

Comment: Have a look at this, that should help I think: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/650460/rotating-a-2d-sprite-to-face-a-target-on-a-single.html

Comment: Tried that, still rotates upside down, I think the Z axis needs to have a max value.

Comment: You had a look at the comments below the marked answer? I think your problem is not directly related to the rotation, but to the settings like sprite pivot and so on. You are rotating aroung a single axis so it shouldn't be possible to flip around another (which it does, when it flips up side down).

Comment: yeah, pivot point has nothing to do with it. Thanks.